# s.tk/gaming does: The Old Republic

Tags: discussion, community

Some have thrown around the idea of a GamingSE guild, or others have their own, so at the very least to begin, who's where (what server) and for something more protracted, who has plans to do what?

I'm not sure if it would be better or worse from a QA-feeding point of view to be on a server with someone you know or not, seems like there are reasons for either, though if you're chatting up people you know one of you could try to turn passing questions into something more.

Comment: Is this about SW:TOR?

Comment: @badp yes. The Old Republic is what TOR stands for.

Comment: I'm betting some folks haven't made plans yet. The game doesn't come out for another 2 days, after all.

Comment: Early access was granted as early as last Tuesday for a lot of people, a full week before store launch though. I'm like the only one in my guild that doesn't have the game yet, the rest of them pre-ordered online.

Answer (score 3):

Servers you have a character on:

- **Peragus Mining Facility**

  - *Empire*

    - Svick
- **Thana Vesh**

  - *Republic*

    - Matt Read
- **The Constant**

  - *Republic*

    - Nick T
  - *Empire*

    - Nick T
- **The Twin Spears**

  - *Republic*

    - Kitt
  - *Empire*

    - Hunt

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: Shouldn't people also put which side they're on?

Comment: I'm open to making new characters on other servers as well.